# Creating Random Number

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to the programming world and am trying my hand at a simple math app.  Basically i want to app to create two random numbers and then add them together.  I then put the answer in a text field where the app checks to see if the answer is right or wrong.  I have created this and it works however I cannot get the numbers to regenerate after the answer is correct.  Any direction you can give on this I would be much appreciative.

Here is the code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.guess(self)

}

    @IBOutlet weak var addend1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var addend2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var answer: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var response: UILabel!

    //create numbers
    let newaddend1 = arc4random() % 11
    let newaddend2 = arc4random() % 11

    @IBAction func guess(sender: AnyObject) {

    //Convert Random Numbers to String to be displayed in labels
    var firstNumber = String(newaddend1)
    var secondNumber = String(newaddend2)

    //convert the answer in the text field to an integer
    var integer = answer?.text.toInt()

    //Convert Strings to Ints so they can be added
    var newFirstNumber = firstNumber.toInt()
    var newSecondNumber = secondNumber.toInt()

    //Add Numbers
    var correctAnswer = (newFirstNumber! + newSecondNumber!)

    //Display the numbers
    addend1.text = firstNumber
    addend2.text = secondNumber

    //Print correct number to log for test
    println(correctAnswer)
    println(integer)

    //check your answer agains the correct answer
    if (integer != nil) {
        if (integer == correctAnswer) {

            response.text = "Correct! The Answer is \(correctAnswer)!"

        } else {

            response.text = "Wrongo Bongo the correct answer is \(correctAnswer)!"
        }

    } else {

        response.text = "Please put in a number for your guess"

    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//remove keyboard
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {

    answer.resignFirstResponder()
    return true

}

}
```

Comment: You're new to programming??  What the heck are you doing programming in Swift??  It's not a beginner's language!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize the variables outside of the IBAction to get class level variable declaration.  Then immediately calculate new random numbers once the correct answer is generated:

```
   let newaddend1 = 0
    let newaddend2 = 0

    @IBAction func guess(sender: AnyObject) {

    //Convert Random Numbers to String to be displayed in labels
    var firstNumber = String(newaddend1)
    var secondNumber = String(newaddend2)

    //convert the answer in the text field to an integer
    var integer = answer?.text.toInt()

    //Convert Strings to Ints so they can be added
    var newFirstNumber = firstNumber.toInt()
    var newSecondNumber = secondNumber.toInt()

    //Add Numbers
    var correctAnswer = (newFirstNumber! + newSecondNumber!)

    //Display the numbers
    addend1.text = firstNumber
    addend2.text = secondNumber

    //Print correct number to log for test
    println(correctAnswer)
    println(integer)

    //check your answer agains the correct answer
    if (integer != nil) {
        if (integer == correctAnswer) {

            response.text = "Correct! The Answer is \(correctAnswer)!"

           let newaddend1 = arc4random() % 11
           let newaddend2 = arc4random() % 11
        } else {

            response.text = "Wrongo Bongo the correct answer is \(correctAnswer)!"
        }

    } else {

        response.text = "Please put in a number for your guess"

    }
}
```